# Can you reuse cURL connection caches between uses?

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, curl

From the [Everything curl book](https://ec.haxx.se/usingcurl/usingcurl-persist), reusing curl connections by combining command lines can provide a performance increase, but the connection cache and other caches are cleared each time an individual curl command exits.

> ...curl will always try to keep connections alive and reuse existing connections as far as it can.
>   The curl command-line tool can, however, only keep connections alive for as long as it runs, so as soon as it exits back to your command line it has to close down all currently open connections (and also free and clean up all the other caches it uses to decrease time of subsequent operations). We call the pool of alive connections the "connection cache".

I use curl to grab data from a URL, which I then use to form my next curl request. I want to benefit from the connection reuse, since I'm returning to the same server (sometimes even the same page), but I can't just combine commands because the second command depends on information returned by the first.

In pseudocode

```
webdata="$(curl somerepository)"  # read a web page full of package links
webdata=findPackage($webdata)     # do some text processing on the page data to isolate a specific filename
curl somerepository/${webdata} -O # download a package using its filename
```

Is there a way for me to benefit from connection reuse in this case, by preventing an active connection from closing, finding a way to prevent the cache of closed connections from being cleared, or something else?

Comment: I did read [this somewhat similar question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/393640/how-to-access-http-server-from-bash-script-with-existing-tcp-connection) but the requirements seem pretty different; I feel like a tunnel would be overkill here.